# $f(x)=4x^4+6x^3+2x^2+203x-(203)^2$ , Is the local extrema of $f'(x)$ positive or negative? And how?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, optimization

Here's a question that I found in a JEE Advanced practice paper:

> Consider a function, $f(x)=4x^4+6x^3+2x^2+203x-(203)^2$
>
> **Q.** The local extrema of $f'(x)$ is
>   (a) positive
>   (b) negative
>   (c) zero
>   (d) data insufficient

The answer given is:

> Notice that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=+\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)=-\infty$$
>   And $f''(x)$ has 2 real roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1>x_2$. (*) Hence the local minimum value ($m$) of $f'(x)$ is $+$ and $x_1\in(-1,0),m>0$.

I understood it upto the point which I marked (*). They mean to say that the graph of $f'(x)$ looks like this: [image]

So far we dont have any info about the position of extrema on x or y axis, we only know that they exist. However after (*) they sudenly say thatthe maxima is +ve and in some interval. How did they get it?

**TLDR**: I didn't get the last line of the answer. Can someone explain please how the got they last line?

Comment: Are you sure $f(x)$ is written so? Its derivative $f'(x)$ has a [negative local minimum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx(4x%5E4%2B6x%5E3%2B2x%5E2%2B203-(203)%5E2))

Comment: @delt31 sorry i forgot to write an x

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic is like this:

- $f'(x)=16x^3+18x^2+4x+203,\ f''(x)=48x^2+36x+4$
- [Contents up to (*)]
- $f'(x)$ attains minimum at $x=x_1$. (As the graph shown)
- $f''(x)>0$ for $x\le -1$ or $x\ge 0$, so $x_1 \in (-1,0)$.
- For $x\in (-1,0)$, $f'(x)$ is positive, in particular $f'(x_1)$, done.

Though I am not sure what is the sentence "Hence the local minimum value (m) of f′(x) is +..." supposed to tell.

Comment: ok thanks ... now I get it.